# jQuery UI tabs where the tabs and their contents fill 100% of the available space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm struggling with this seemingly easy task: making jQuery UI tabs fill a window (100% height and width) while setting the tab content divs to fill the available space.

Here's what I'm dealing with: http://jsfiddle.net/rgw2raej/

In this example, the "red box" is much longer than the tab's available space even though it's set to 100% height.  How can I get it to fill the tab's available space?

Here's the code (because Stack Overflow told me to):

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tabs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#tabs-1, #tabs-2, #tabs-3 {
    border: 5px solid red !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
  $(function () {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-standing CSS bugbear, and there are some truly ugly solutions out there.

Finally, CSS3 delivers an elegant-ish solution. It's called 'flex'.

Remove the "height:100%" rules, and replace them with:

```
#tabs {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex:1;
}
#tabs-1, #tabs-2, #tabs-3 {
    flex:1;
}
```

Here's your page with this code added: http://jsfiddle.net/bgxpc9y9/

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!  It looks like display:flex isn't very compatible with a lot of browsers yet, however: http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/9cc702e259c7cab93b9dc62397d468f7528933f8  Can you think of a cross-browser solution?

Comment: There is a page here: https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/  ... that talks about the various hacks to make it work with at least some of those recalcitrant browsers. Sorry I don't have the time right now to go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `position: absolute` on `#tabs`, use `display: block`.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgw2raej/1/

Comment: The jQuery tabs aren't filling the available space of the window in this example.